# Closure inside function / need explanation

Tags: swift, function, syntax, closures

I'm studying [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) and saw a *unknown (for me)* example of the use of closures in function in the book:

```
func counter() -> () -> Int {
    var count = 0
    let incrementer: () -> Int = {
        count += 1
        return count
    }
    return incrementer
}
```

But I've never seen such a way of creating a closure. I've tried the usual one method and that worked too:

```
func counter() -> Int {
    var count = 0
    let incrementer = { () -> Int in
        count += 1
        return count
    }
    return incrementer()
}
```

How does it work? Is it just a type annotation?

Comment: In one you are returning the closure and the other it is the result of a closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both provided functions are counters and you can write this using either `counter()()` or `counter()`. They appear to be the same, at first, but you will find that you cannot use `counter()` more than once because it has only one value, `1`, meaning that you used unnecessary steps to make a basic `Int` var. However, on the other hand, you have `counter()()`, which counts up like a function after defining an owner pointer via the `var` keyword.

So, one defines, uses and deallocates a closure, while the other defines a closure and returns it allowing for reuse.

Comment: Counter()() is made of a function that makes a closure and then runs it, this was stated like this to give identity to both functions due to their identical names. counter() == counter()() would return true as they both respond with 1 initially but var spoons = counter(); spoon()/*1*/; spoon()/*2*/; var ifd = counter()/*1*/; ifd/*1*/; ifd()/*Error*/; ifd += 1/*2*/; shows the differences between with code

Comment: Why post a comment to your answer that is as long as your answer? Why not update your answer with the additional information?